# How to escape #1 using xpretocmd

Tags: arguments, xpatch

Take this MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{acro}
\DeclareAcronym{ram}{short=RAM, long=random access memory}
\newcommand{\test}[1]{RAM}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\begin{document}

\test{ram}

% This works:
\xpretocmd{\test}{#1=}{}{}
\test{ram}


\acs{ram}

% This does not, it outputs "#1":
\xpretocmd{\acroprintfield}{#1=}{}{}
\acs{ram}

\end{document}
```

So there does not seem to be a general need to "escape" (or otherwise treat) `#` in `xpatch`, but it seems there is with certain commands. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `\acroprintfield` is defined using `xparse`, and `xparse`-defined commands are not patchable by `xpatch` (see section 5 Limitations and warnings in the documentation)

Comment: This is related to our discussion here https://github.com/cgnieder/acro/issues/193, isn't it? What are you trying to do that you want to patch the command? I showed you a redefinition. I am even willing to change the internals so you can get a _safe_ redefinition…

Comment: @cgnieder yes - I am trying to translate your proposed approach into one that does not require `expl3` syntax in order to get to a solution that I can understand and maintain myself without further nagging you with my ignorance :) I'll share what I have as soon as it's done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a quick hence incomplete workaround, you can patch `\acroprintfield code` (this is a single control sequence with a space in its name), which stores the real body of `\acroprintfield`.

I'm not familiar with `acro` and didn't read through https://github.com/cgnieder/acro/issues/193. It's highly possible that you can achieve a nicer solution (e.g., configurable user interface) from the `acro` side.

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{acro}
\DeclareAcronym{ram}{short=RAM, long=random access memory}
\newcommand{\test}[1]{RAM}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\begin{document}

\test{ram} % get "RAM"

% This works:
\xpretocmd{\test}{#1=}{}{}

\test{ram} % get "ram=RAM"


\acs{ram}  % get "RAM"

% This works too:
\ExplSyntaxOn
\expandafter\xpretocmd
  \csname acroprintfield~ code\endcsname
  {#1=}
  {}{\fail}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\acs{ram}  % get "ram=RAM"

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My workaround looks like this:

```latex
let\oldacroprintfield\acroprintfield​
​\renewcommand​{​\acroprintfield​}[2]{​%​
       #1=\oldacroprintfield​{#1}{#2}}
```